# Is it possible to extract the value from processing-instruction ('define') with XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath, wix, processing-instruction

I would like to extract the version number from this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Include>
  <?define ProductVersion = "1.0.0.0" ?>
</Include>
```

I want the output to be: `1.0.0.0`, is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio to create the WIX based installer then you can define your `ProductVersion` variable in the `.wixproj` file.

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <DefineConstants>ProductVersion=1.0</DefineConstants>
      ...
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
```

This would be accessible from .wxs file by `$(var.ProductVersion)`. Now you can use XPath to read the value of `DefineConstants` from your .wixproj file. This will get you `ProductVersion = "1.0.0.0"`

Answer (score 1):

You can access the processing instruction content using the `processing-instruction()` node filter. There is no semantic defined within a processing instruction, so you  cannot directly query for the "attribute value".

You can use this XPath (1.0) query to fetch the value using string processing:

```
substring-before(substring-after(/Include/processing-instruction(), '"'), '"')
```